# Rolling Weekly Date Range for Excel Pivot Table not including this week

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a helper column so that I can have a dynamic / rolling date range for my pivot table.  I update this data table every day.  The number of rows for each start date will vary based on the shift and data that is collected in columns not pictured below.

Column B contains the week start date based on the Shift Start Date that is in Column A.  I would like to insert a Column C that would say "Yes" if the date in column B is within in the previous 6 weeks (not counting the current week of NOW() ).  This way I can show data compiled only from full/completed weeks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar to this would work

```
=IF(AND(WEEKNUM(TODAY(),1)-WEEKNUM(A5,1)<=6,WEEKNUM(TODAY(),1)-WEEKNUM(A5,1)>0),"yes","no")
```

It's using [weeknum](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WEEKNUM-function-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340) which returns the week number in the year of the date. It wouldn't work if you're going from december to january though. With that you would just need to count the days.

Comment: Thanks!  I kept getting stuck on how to get rid of the current week.  That formula works great!

Comment: If you take the approach of counting days, just use the same structure, just making sure that the difference is `>7` or whatever